# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after splitting a string

Tags: java, string, split, hashmap, hashset

I am getting the following error when trying to submit this code to hackerrank on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/contacts/problem:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
> at Result.contacts(Solution.java:31)
> at Solution.main(Solution.java:66)

However, it seems to work on my local machine, but I am not sure if there is a problem after splitting the words. It seems to be split properly as I check by debugging, but I am not sure if I need to use an extra check after split. Or there may be a problem for split.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> s = List.of("add hack", "add hackerrank", "find hac", "find hak");
    List<List<String>> queries = Collections.singletonList(s);
    List<Integer> result = contacts(queries);
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static List<Integer> contacts(List<List<String>> queries) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<String> query : queries) {
        for (String s : query) {

            // !!! the problem may be caused from these lines >>>
            String operation = s.split(" ")[0];
            String word = s.split(" ")[1];

            if (operation.equals("add")) {
                set.add(word);
            } else if (operation.equals("find")) {
                long count = set.stream().filter(c -> c.startsWith(word)).count();
                result.add((int) count);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, what may the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is how you interpreted what "query" is. *Operation* and *Word* are not in a single String. they are elements in the query. Therefore...

```
for (List<String> query : queries) {
    String operation = query.get(0);
    String word = query.get(1);
    // The rest of your code;
}
```

[image]

This is for people who love to comment without trying their own suggestions first.
[image]